# Connecing to OracleDB using SID with node-oracledb fails

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I am trying to connect to Oracle DB using SID and getting the below error

Error getting the connection - **Error: ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist**

I have tried following connect strings :

HOST:1521:SID

HOST:1521/SID

HOST, PORT and SID are all correct and I am able to connect using DBVisualizer.

Also, I am able to connect successfully using the SERVICE NAME with both DBVisualizer and node application.

Can someone help me out in connecting with SID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are connecting to Oracle Database 12c.
By default you no longer can connect using HOST:PORT:SID. If you still need to, add the parameter `USE_SID_AS_SERVICE_listener=on` to your `listener.ora` file and reload (`lsnrctl reload`)

For more information: 
https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/multitenant-connecting-to-cdb-and-pdb-12cr1

Comment: It might be better to make the leap and find the actual service name.  BTW, the Easy Connect syntax has always been host:port/service_name.  It's never supported a SID.